# ls says file exists, but file says no such file or directory

Tags: shell, ls, devices

So when I were tweaking my laptop touchpad input, I came across this directory, and I found something weird.

Maybe checking the command output is better than me trying to describe it:

```
[root@T480-arch serio1]# pwd -P
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1
[root@T480-arch serio1]# file ./*
./bind_mode:   ASCII text
./description: ASCII text
./driver:      symbolic link to ../../../../bus/serio/drivers/psmouse
./drvctl:      writable, regular file, no read permission
./firmware_id: ASCII text
./id:          directory
./modalias:    ASCII text
./power:       directory
./protocol:    ASCII text
./rate:        ERROR: cannot read `./rate' (No such file or directory)
./resetafter:  ERROR: cannot read `./resetafter' (No such file or directory)
./resolution:  ERROR: cannot read `./resolution' (No such file or directory)
./resync_time: ERROR: cannot read `./resync_time' (No such file or directory)
./subsystem:   symbolic link to ../../../../bus/serio
./uevent:      ASCII text
[root@T480-arch serio1]# ls -alFtr | grep -iE "rate|resetafter|resolution|resync_time"
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul 30 02:28 resync_time
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul 30 02:28 resolution
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul 30 02:28 resetafter
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul 30 02:28 rate
```

As shown, `bash` and `ls` both knows that there's 4 r-something files, and that `root` have permissions, but `file` command don't recognize them.

In addition, if I try to edit them with `vim`:

```
"rate" [READ ERRORS] 0L, 0C
```

My question is, what are some possible reasons such that conditions like this could occur?
And to be specific, what "file" am I dealing with?

Since it's under `/sys/`, I suppose it's not a genuine file per se, but some abstraction like what we usually see under `/dev/`, thanks to the

> Everything is a file

philosophy of *nix systems. But in that case, `file` should tell me it's a device file or something, which is not the case here.

Comment: `/sys` is a pseudo-file system (sysfs), you can have very strange files there.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57417401

Comment: @Quasimodo helped a lot! I knew it's some abstraction instead of real files, but didn't quite think about that it hence need its own read/write implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/sys` is a virtual file system, and files therein aren’t really files, they’re interfaces into the kernel. The four files you’ve encountered are handled by the `psmouse` driver, and they have the unusual behaviour of [returning `ENOENT` on reads](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.8/source/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse-base.c#L1815) if the device being examined has an “SMBus companion”. (This is a common feature of trackpads on laptops — they are exposed as PS/2 devices for backward compatibility, and also as devices on other buses which provide access to all their features.)

As a general rule, you can’t expect most file-accessing tools to work as-is on files under `/sys`. In particular, many of them need to be read in one operation, and their apparent length often has no basis in reality.